# Debug 'app' is ok but fail to run 'app' in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am using Android Studio to debug my app, when I click the Debug 'app' button to run my app, everything works fine, but when I click the Run 'app' button to run my app, the app crashes, part of the log:

```
01-01 08:15:57.910 31532-31544/com.yuzhix.homedot V/EasyConfigManager-JNI: managerCallback: callbackInfo 0x546a7008, easyConfigManager_ref 0x401391b8 easyConfigManager_class 0x401391b8
01-01 08:15:57.910 31532-31544/com.yuzhix.homedot V/EasyConfigManager-JNI: EVENT_COMPLETE
01-01 08:15:57.910 31532-31544/com.yuzhix.homedot W/dalvikvm: Invalid indirect reference 0x401391b8 in decodeIndirectRef
01-01 08:15:57.910 31532-31544/com.yuzhix.homedot I/dalvikvm: "Binder_2" prio=5 tid=10 RUNNABLE
01-01 08:15:57.910 31532-31544/com.yuzhix.homedot I/dalvikvm:   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x41a077d0 self=0x546a2440
01-01 08:15:57.910 31532-31544/com.yuzhix.homedot I/dalvikvm:   | sysTid=31544 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=1426889576
01-01 08:15:57.910 31532-31544/com.yuzhix.homedot I/dalvikvm:   | state=R schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=1
01-01 08:15:57.910 31532-31544/com.yuzhix.homedot I/dalvikvm:     at com.softwinner.easyconfig.EasyConfigManager.postEventFromNative(EasyConfigManager.java:-1)
01-01 08:15:57.910 31532-31544/com.yuzhix.homedot I/dalvikvm:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
01-01 08:15:57.910 31532-31544/com.yuzhix.homedot E/dalvikvm: VM aborting
01-01 08:15:57.910 31532-31544/com.yuzhix.homedot A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT) at 0x00007b2c (code=-6), thread 31544 (Binder_2)
01-01 08:15:57.910 689-991/? E/IEasyConfigClient: enableStatusChanged
01-01 08:15:57.910 689-991/? E/EasyConfigService: #######state change to:STATE_STOPED
01-01 08:15:57.910 512-545/system_process D/PowerManagerService: Check if boot animation finished...
01-01 08:15:58.020 105-105/? I/DEBUG: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
01-01 08:15:58.020 105-105/? I/DEBUG: Build fingerprint: 'Allwinner-Speaker/lark_pro/lark-pro:4.4.2/KVT49L/20170420:eng/test-keys'
01-01 08:15:58.020 105-105/? I/DEBUG: Revision: '0'
01-01 08:15:58.020 105-105/? I/DEBUG: pid: 31532, tid: 31544, name: Binder_2  >>> com.yuzhix.homedot <<<
01-01 08:15:58.020 105-105/? I/DEBUG: signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
01-01 08:15:58.110 512-545/system_process D/PowerManagerService: Check if boot animation finished...
01-01 08:15:58.170 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     r0 00000000  r1 00007b38  r2 00000006  r3 00000000
01-01 08:15:58.170 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     r4 00000006  r5 00000002  r6 00007b38  r7 0000010c
01-01 08:15:58.170 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     r8 51565b30  r9 55b2f5b0  sl 00000001  fp 556cebc0
01-01 08:15:58.170 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     ip 556d4fa8  sp 556ce8b8  lr 400fe065  pc 4010cfa0  cpsr 000f0010
01-01 08:15:58.170 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     d0  74726f6261204d56  d1  726174536576696e
01-01 08:15:58.170 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     d2  6e614d6769666e75  d3  736f702e7265676c
01-01 08:15:58.170 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     d4  0079007300610045  d5  0066006e006f0043
01-01 08:15:58.170 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     d6  006c004300670069  d7  0074006e00650069
01-01 08:15:58.170 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     d8  0000000000000000  d9  0000000000000000
01-01 08:15:58.170 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     d10 0000000000000000  d11 0000000000000000
01-01 08:15:58.170 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
01-01 08:15:58.170 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
01-01 08:15:58.170 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     d16 ffffffffffffefff  d17 0000000000000005
01-01 08:15:58.170 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     d18 0000000000000000  d19 0000000000000000
01-01 08:15:58.170 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     d20 0000000000004000  d21 0000000000000000
01-01 08:15:58.170 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     d22 0000000000004000  d23 0000000000000000
01-01 08:15:58.170 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     d24 0000000000000000  d25 0000000000000000
01-01 08:15:58.170 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     d26 0000000000000000  d27 0000000000000000
01-01 08:15:58.170 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     d28 0000000000000000  d29 0000000000000000
01-01 08:15:58.170 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     d30 0000000000000000  d31 0000000000004000
01-01 08:15:58.170 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     scr 80000010
01-01 08:15:58.180 105-105/? I/DEBUG: backtrace:
01-01 08:15:58.180 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     #00  pc 00021fa0  /system/lib/libc.so (tgkill+12)
01-01 08:15:58.180 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     #01  pc 00013061  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_kill+48)
01-01 08:15:58.180 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     #02  pc 00013275  /system/lib/libc.so (raise+10)
01-01 08:15:58.180 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     #03  pc 00011fa9  /system/lib/libc.so
01-01 08:15:58.180 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     #04  pc 00021854  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+4)
01-01 08:15:58.180 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     #05  pc 00045b9b  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmAbort+78)
01-01 08:15:58.180 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     #06  pc 0004a4ab  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmDecodeIndirectRef(Thread*, _jobject*)+146)
01-01 08:15:58.180 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     #07  pc 00060383  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethodV(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, bool, JValue*, std::__va_list)+158)
01-01 08:15:58.180 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     #08  pc 00049bdb  /system/lib/libdvm.so
01-01 08:15:58.180 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     #09  pc 00004957  /system/lib/libeasyconfigmanager_jni.so
01-01 08:15:58.180 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     #10  pc 00004a57  /system/lib/libeasyconfigmanager_jni.so
01-01 08:15:58.180 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     #11  pc 00004e33  /system/lib/libeasyconfigmanager_jni.so (android::EasyConfigManager::onConfigCompleted(char const*, char const*, int)+54)
01-01 08:15:58.180 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     #12  pc 000052eb  /system/lib/libeasyconfigmanager_jni.so (android::BnEasyConfigClient::onTransact(unsigned int, android::Parcel const&, android::Parcel*, unsigned int)+134)
01-01 08:15:58.180 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     #13  pc 000191ad  /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::BBinder::transact(unsigned int, android::Parcel const&, android::Parcel*, unsigned int)+60)
01-01 08:15:58.180 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     #14  pc 0001d721  /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::executeCommand(int)+508)
01-01 08:15:58.180 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     #15  pc 0001da9f  /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::getAndExecuteCommand()+38)
01-01 08:15:58.180 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     #16  pc 0001db15  /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::joinThreadPool(bool)+48)
01-01 08:15:58.180 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     #17  pc 0002191d  /system/lib/libbinder.so
01-01 08:15:58.180 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     #18  pc 0000ea01  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+216)
01-01 08:15:58.180 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     #19  pc 0004d2a5  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::javaThreadShell(void*)+68)
01-01 08:15:58.180 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     #20  pc 0000e533  /system/lib/libutils.so
01-01 08:15:58.180 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     #21  pc 0000d208  /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+72)
01-01 08:15:58.180 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     #22  pc 0000d3a4  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+240)
01-01 08:15:58.180 105-105/? I/DEBUG: stack:
01-01 08:15:58.190 105-105/? I/DEBUG:          556ce878  dead4321  
01-01 08:15:58.190 105-105/? I/DEBUG:          556ce87c  546a2440  [anon:libc_malloc]
01-01 08:15:58.190 105-105/? I/DEBUG:          556ce880  556d4fa8  
01-01 08:15:58.190 105-105/? I/DEBUG:          556ce884  51565b30  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-LinearAlloc (deleted)
01-01 08:15:58.190 105-105/? I/DEBUG:          556ce888  55b2f5b0  /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@com.yuzhix.homedot-1.apk@classes.dex
01-01 08:15:58.190 105-105/? I/DEBUG:          556ce88c  00000001  
01-01 08:15:58.190 105-105/? I/DEBUG:          556ce890  556cebc0  [stack:31544]
01-01 08:15:58.190 105-105/? I/DEBUG:          556ce894  40111561  /system/lib/libc.so (snprintf+80)
01-01 08:15:58.190 105-105/? I/DEBUG:          556ce898  33313833  
01-01 08:15:58.190 105-105/? I/DEBUG:          556ce89c  20302038  
01-01 08:15:58.190 105-105/? I/DEBUG:          556ce8a0  556ce914  [stack:31544]
01-01 08:15:58.190 105-105/? I/DEBUG:          556ce8a4  00000000  
01-01 08:15:58.190 105-105/? I/DEBUG:          556ce8a8  00000000  
01-01 08:15:58.190 105-105/? I/DEBUG:          556ce8ac  30203020  
01-01 08:15:58.190 105-105/? I/DEBUG:          556ce8b0  00004000  
01-01 08:15:58.190 105-105/? I/DEBUG:          556ce8b4  556ce922  [stack:31544]
01-01 08:15:58.190 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     #00  556ce8b8  00000006  
01-01 08:15:58.190 105-105/? I/DEBUG:          556ce8bc  00000002  
01-01 08:15:58.190 105-105/? I/DEBUG:          556ce8c0  00007b38  
01-01 08:15:58.190 105-105/? I/DEBUG:          556ce8c4  556d4fa8  
01-01 08:15:58.190 105-105/? I/DEBUG:          556ce8c8  556d4fa8  
01-01 08:15:58.190 105-105/? I/DEBUG:          556ce8cc  400fe065  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_kill+52)
01-01 08:15:58.190 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     #01  556ce8d0  00000006  
01-01 08:15:58.190 105-105/? I/DEBUG:          556ce8d4  dead4321  
01-01 08:15:58.190 105-105/? I/DEBUG:          556ce8d8  546a2440  [anon:libc_malloc]
01-01 08:15:58.190 105-105/? I/DEBUG:          556ce8dc  400fe279  /system/lib/libc.so (raise+14)
01-01 08:15:58.190 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     #02  556ce8e0  556ce8ec  [stack:31544]
01-01 08:15:58.190 105-105/? I/DEBUG:          556ce8e4  400fcfad  /system/lib/libc.so
01-01 08:15:58.210 105-105/? I/DEBUG: memory near r1:
01-01 08:15:58.210 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     00007b18 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
01-01 08:15:58.210 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     00007b28 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
01-01 08:15:58.210 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     00007b38 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
01-01 08:15:58.210 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     00007b48 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
01-01 08:15:58.210 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     00007b58 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
01-01 08:15:58.210 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     00007b68 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
01-01 08:15:58.210 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     00007b78 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
01-01 08:15:58.210 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     00007b88 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
01-01 08:15:58.210 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     00007b98 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
01-01 08:15:58.210 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     00007ba8 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
01-01 08:15:58.210 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     00007bb8 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
01-01 08:15:58.210 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     00007bc8 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
01-01 08:15:58.210 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     00007bd8 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
01-01 08:15:58.210 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     00007be8 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
01-01 08:15:58.210 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     00007bf8 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
01-01 08:15:58.210 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     00007c08 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
01-01 08:15:58.210 105-105/? I/DEBUG: memory near r6:
01-01 08:15:58.210 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     00007b18 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
01-01 08:15:58.210 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     00007b28 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
01-01 08:15:58.210 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     00007b38 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
01-01 08:15:58.210 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     00007b48 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
01-01 08:15:58.210 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     00007b58 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
01-01 08:15:58.210 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     00007b68 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
01-01 08:15:58.210 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     00007b78 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
01-01 08:15:58.210 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     00007b88 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
01-01 08:15:58.210 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     00007b98 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
01-01 08:15:58.210 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     00007ba8 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
01-01 08:15:58.210 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     00007bb8 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
01-01 08:15:58.210 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     00007bc8 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
01-01 08:15:58.210 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     00007bd8 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
01-01 08:15:58.210 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     00007be8 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
01-01 08:15:58.210 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     00007bf8 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
01-01 08:15:58.210 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     00007c08 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff  
01-01 08:15:58.210 105-105/? I/DEBUG: memory near r8:
01-01 08:15:58.210 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     51565b10 00001877 55b2f06c 55f6e73d 00000000  
01-01 08:15:58.210 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     51565b20 41574e65 00000100 00000000 00000000  
01-01 08:15:58.210 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     51565b30 41a0a4c8 0000000a 000b0000 00070004  
01-01 08:15:58.210 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     51565b40 55b78043 546a6558 00002061 55b2f5af  
01-01 08:15:58.210 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     51565b50 558f3350 00000000 00000000 00000000  
01-01 08:15:58.210 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     51565b60 55ca81ad 00000000 00000000 0000011c  
01-01 08:15:58.210 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     51565b70 41a0a4c8 00000004 00010002 00010001  
01-01 08:15:58.210 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     51565b80 55b4e232 546a6558 00001877 55b2f06c  
01-01 08:15:58.210 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     51565b90 558f33c4 00000000 00000000 00000000  
01-01 08:15:58.210 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     51565ba0 55ca81c9 00000000 41a0a4c8 00000001  
01-01 08:15:58.210 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     51565bb0 0002000b 00010001 55b59d83 546a6558  
01-01 08:15:58.210 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     51565bc0 0000003d 55acf994 558f33dc 00000000  
01-01 08:15:58.210 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     51565bd0 00000000 00000000 55ca81d1 00000000  
01-01 08:15:58.220 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     51565be0 41a0a4c8 00000001 0004000c 00020001  
01-01 08:15:58.220 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     51565bf0 55b82a84 546a6558 00001e73 55b2f4fa  
01-01 08:15:58.220 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     51565c00 558f33f8 00000000 00000000 00000000  
01-01 08:15:58.220 105-105/? I/DEBUG: memory near r9:
01-01 08:15:58.220 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     55b2f590 07004949 49494c56 004c4949 494c5608  
01-01 08:15:58.220 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     55b2f5a0 4c494949 56060049 4949494c 5608004c  
01-01 08:15:58.220 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     55b2f5b0 4949494c 00494c4c 494c5606 005a4949  
01-01 08:15:58.220 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     55b2f5c0 494c5607 4c5a4949 4c560600 4c4a4949  
01-01 08:15:58.220 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     55b2f5d0 4c560500 004c4949 494c5606 004c4c49  
01-01 08:15:58.220 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     55b2f5e0 494c560b 4c4c4c49 4c4c4c4c 4c560500  
01-01 08:15:58.220 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     55b2f5f0 005a4949 494c5606 004a464a 494c5604  
01-01 08:15:58.220 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     55b2f600 5605004c 494c494c 4c560600 49494c49  
01-01 08:15:58.220 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     55b2f610 4c560700 49494c49 56080049 494c494c  
01-01 08:15:58.220 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     55b2f620 004c4949 494c5606 004c494c 494c5607  
01-01 08:15:58.220 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     55b2f630 4c4c494c 4c560500 004c4c49 494c5606  
01-01 08:15:58.220 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     55b2f640 004c4c4c 494c5607 494c4c4c 4c560700  
01-01 08:15:58.220 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     55b2f650 4c4c4c49 5605004c 5a4c494c 4c560600  
01-01 08:15:58.220 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     55b2f660 5a5a4c49 4c560400 03005a49 004a4c56  
01-01 08:15:58.220 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     55b2f670 4a4c5604 56040042 00464a4c 4a4c5604  
01-01 08:15:58.220 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     55b2f680 5605004a 4a4a4a4c 4c560500 005a4a4a  
01-01 08:15:58.220 105-105/? I/DEBUG: memory near fp:
01-01 08:15:58.220 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     556ceba0 550c9fb8 55f6e959 550c9fb8 556cebbc  
01-01 08:15:58.220 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     556cebb0 000000f8 55f6ea5b 51565b30 401391b8  
01-01 08:15:58.220 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     556cebc0 00000002 00000000 0000006f 21000001  
01-01 08:15:58.220 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     556cebd0 1da00005 000000f8 00000000 00000000  
01-01 08:15:58.220 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     556cebe0 54474690 546a54f8 000000f8 553c6084  
01-01 08:15:58.220 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     556cebf0 553c6074 00007b2c 555d1000 555c1bd4  
01-01 08:15:58.220 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     556cec00 401372ec 55f6ee35 553c6084 000000f8  
01-01 08:15:58.220 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     556cec10 553c6084 546a6f50 55f6ee41 553c6084  
01-01 08:15:58.220 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     556cec20 553c6074 55f6f2ed 556cecac 546a6f54  
01-01 08:15:58.220 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     556cec30 00000002 556cec7c 00007b2c 4019f1af  
01-01 08:15:58.220 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     556cec40 00000011 00000002 556cec7c 54474bf0  
01-01 08:15:58.220 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     556cec50 556cec78 40139384 00002725 401a3723  
01-01 08:15:58.220 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     556cec60 00000011 401a321d 54474bf0 41587441  
01-01 08:15:58.220 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     556cec70 415b7125 00000000 546a6f54 00000000  
01-01 08:15:58.220 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     556cec80 553c6028 0000006c 0000006c 0000006c  
01-01 08:15:58.220 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     556cec90 553c6094 00000000 00000000 00000000  
01-01 08:15:58.220 105-105/? I/DEBUG: memory near ip:
01-01 08:15:58.220 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     556d4f88 00000000 51565b30 00000000 51276658  
01-01 08:15:58.220 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     556d4f98 5231768a 41a8d4f0 00000001 00000000  
01-01 08:15:58.220 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     556d4fa8 0000002b 00000000 419dea60 00000007  
01-01 08:15:58.220 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     556d4fb8 556cec7c 556cecac 00000011 556d4fec  
01-01 08:15:58.220 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     556d4fc8 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
01-01 08:15:58.220 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     556d4fd8 556d5000 00000000 51282708 00000000  
01-01 08:15:58.220 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     556d4fe8 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
01-01 08:15:58.220 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     556d4ff8 00000000 00000000 ed0aa17c c7867178  
01-01 08:15:58.220 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     556d5008 931dde53 621eda87 fb854887 24cf5998  
01-01 08:15:58.220 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     556d5018 dedfc023 a43ce86d 52705b0b ac00acc0  
01-01 08:15:58.220 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     556d5028 6778f39f d9b80d62 6cab48ec 171c39b4  
01-01 08:15:58.220 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     556d5038 2e3c59e0 a82f5962 29f96f79 059fe072  
01-01 08:15:58.220 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     556d5048 91c8e1e2 db09494e 739805ab df55ed25  
01-01 08:15:58.220 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     556d5058 b2c1a1c6 489ffa9c 2f7b05c1 f2acd64c  
01-01 08:15:58.220 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     556d5068 b486e7e2 fbc10c8d 8de2060c a4641de2  
01-01 08:15:58.220 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     556d5078 b623b056 fa4f4186 b6e3b3ee 9a4f5741  
01-01 08:15:58.220 105-105/? I/DEBUG: memory near sp:
01-01 08:15:58.220 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     556ce898 33313833 20302038 556ce914 00000000  
01-01 08:15:58.220 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     556ce8a8 00000000 30203020 00004000 556ce922  
01-01 08:15:58.220 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     556ce8b8 00000006 00000002 00007b38 556d4fa8  
01-01 08:15:58.220 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     556ce8c8 556d4fa8 400fe065 00000006 dead4321  
01-01 08:15:58.220 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     556ce8d8 546a2440 400fe279 556ce8ec 400fcfad  
01-01 08:15:58.220 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     556ce8e8 00000000 ffffffdf 401352c4 4013522c  
01-01 08:15:58.220 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     556ce8f8 00000000 400ffb5f 415d61f0 415d61f0  
01-01 08:15:58.220 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     556ce908 dead4321 4010c858 00000000 4156cb9f  
01-01 08:15:58.220 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     556ce918 40143324 6c756e28 0000296c 00000000  
01-01 08:15:58.220 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     556ce928 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
01-01 08:15:58.230 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     556ce938 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
01-01 08:15:58.230 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     556ce948 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
01-01 08:15:58.230 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     556ce958 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
01-01 08:15:58.230 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     556ce968 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
01-01 08:15:58.230 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     556ce978 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
01-01 08:15:58.230 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     556ce988 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  
01-01 08:15:58.230 105-105/? I/DEBUG: code around pc:
01-01 08:15:58.230 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     4010cf80 e8bd00f0 e3700a01 912fff1e e2600000  
01-01 08:15:58.230 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     4010cf90 ea006e76 e92d50f0 e3a07f43 ef000000  
01-01 08:15:58.230 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     4010cfa0 e8bd50f0 e3700a01 912fff1e e2600000  
01-01 08:15:58.230 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     4010cfb0 ea006e6e e92d50f0 e3a070ee ef000000  
01-01 08:15:58.230 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     4010cfc0 e8bd50f0 e3700a01 912fff1e e2600000  
01-01 08:15:58.230 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     4010cfd0 ea006e66 e1520003 8a00008c f5d1f040  
01-01 08:15:58.230 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     4010cfe0 e92d4001 e3520010 3a000024 e2603000  
01-01 08:15:58.230 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     4010cff0 e213300f 0a00000e e0422003 e1b0cf83  
01-01 08:15:58.230 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     4010d000 44d1e001 44c0e001 24d1c001 24d1e001  
01-01 08:15:58.230 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     4010d010 24c0c001 24c0e001 e1b0ce83 aa000001  
01-01 08:15:58.230 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     4010d020 f4a1030d f480031d 3a000001 f421070d  
01-01 08:15:58.230 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     4010d030 f400071d e2522040 3a000006 f421020d  
01-01 08:15:58.230 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     4010d040 f421420d f5d1f100 e2522040 f400022d  
01-01 08:15:58.230 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     4010d050 f400422d 2afffff8 e2922020 3a000002  
01-01 08:15:58.230 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     4010d060 f421020d e2422020 f400022d e2822020  
01-01 08:15:58.230 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     4010d070 e3120010 0a000001 f4210a0d f4000a2d  
01-01 08:15:58.230 105-105/? I/DEBUG: code around lr:
01-01 08:15:58.240 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     400fe044 447b4b13 42b3e010 4812d10e 44786a1e  
01-01 08:15:58.240 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     400fe054 ec94f7fb e9d6f00d 46224631 ef98f00e  
01-01 08:15:58.240 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     400fe064 d00a3001 e00b2400 2b00681b 480ad1eb  
01-01 08:15:58.240 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     400fe074 44782403 ec82f7fb f001e002 6804fa1b  
01-01 08:15:58.240 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     400fe084 fa18f001 46206005 bf00bd70 0003b35e  
01-01 08:15:58.240 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     400fe094 0003b352 0003b34a 0003b326 bf7ef7ff  
01-01 08:15:58.240 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     400fe0a4 43f0e92d 4a3d4b3c 589c447b 6823b08b  
01-01 08:15:58.240 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     400fe0b4 460d4606 f0019309 46a1f9fd 8000f8d0  
01-01 08:15:58.240 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     400fe0c4 d0482d00 f00f4628 280ffe69 d8444604  
01-01 08:15:58.240 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     400fe0d4 ffe4f7ff d1064286 4629200f e8a0f00d  
01-01 08:15:58.240 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     400fe0e4 d03c2800 482ee02e f7fb4478 482debc6  
01-01 08:15:58.240 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     400fe0f4 e0154478 d11342b0 482b6a06 f7fb4478  
01-01 08:15:58.240 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     400fe104 4a2aec3e 447a2120 a8014633 f9fef013  
01-01 08:15:58.240 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     400fe114 a8012101 fcfcf01a 46061c42 e011d104  
01-01 08:15:58.240 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     400fe124 28006800 e02cd1e6 46294630 f00d4622  
01-01 08:15:58.240 105-105/? I/DEBUG:     400fe134 1c43e8dc d11e4607 f9bcf001 29046801
```

I thought the reason was proguard rules, but it seems that Run 'app' and Debug 'app' generate the same apk package?

Comment: This seems like an instant run issue. Turn off instant run, clean project and run again.

Comment: I disabled the instant run, but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you may have a race condition, where you are expecting something to be available to the application but are accessing it before is has completed loading or has returned.  The reason it would worn in debug it you are stopping the process giving what is being loaded to complete.  Not knowing the specifics this is what I think.

But you probably knew this already.

Comment: I don't know how you get this point, but you are right and great. My app starts to connect server before it completes the network configuration process. I am still not clear about why it would work in the _Debug 'app'_ way though.

Comment: When you are debugging an app you are most likely stepping through the code which causes a wait, thus allowing your configuration process to complete